# What functions get called before shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation?

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller

I would like to do some initializations before the function `shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation` gets called in a UIViewController. However, after adding some print outs in different functions, this is the order in which these functions apparently get called:

1.- `shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation`

2.- `loadView`

3.- `viewDidLoad`

4.- `shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation` (again)

5.- `viewWillAppear`

...

Moreover, the functions `init` and `initWithNibName` never get called (or at least I never get the print outs).

I thought that either `init` or `initWithNibName` (depending on what method you use) should get called before `shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation`. But I guess I was wrong (or I am doing something wrong?). Maybe this is happening because this view controller is marked as "Is Initial View Controller" in the storyboard editor?

In any case, what are the functions that are automatically called before `shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation` in a UIViewController?

Thank you so much!

**Note**: I know that `shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation` is obsolete since 6.0, but I want my app to be compatible with 5.0 too.

**Edit**: I only want to initialise a few variables before `shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation`, and I want to do this only once, not every time `shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation` gets called.

Answer (score 0):

You can do whatever setup you need to do in `shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation` just before returning `YES` or `NO` by overriding this method:

In your implementation:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
  // do whatever is needed before the rotation actually happens

  return YES;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I just want to do that initialization once (I guess I should have added that to the question...).

Comment: Then store a BOOL in your delegate that is set when you did the initialization and check for this in `shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation`.

Comment: Yes, I could do that. However I hoping to get a more elegant solution. Thanks anyway!

Comment: If you don't like my answer, you'll probably should explain in more detail, what and why you want to achieve more precisely. If not, you could accept my answer... ;-)